# How can I add a constraint like a column has specific value when another column is null or not null?

Tags: postgresql, knex.js

Here are my seed data rows:

```js
{ organization_id: 1, parent_id: null, organization_type: OrganizationType.ORG },
{ organization_id: 2, parent_id: 1, organization_type: OrganizationType.CLIENT },
{ organization_id: 3, parent_id: 1, organization_type: OrganizationType.CLIENT }
```

I want to add a constraint to `organizations` table.

This constraint has these rules:

1. `organization_type` should be `OrganizationType.ORG`, when `parent_id` is `null`
2. `organization_type` should be `OrganizationType.CLIENT`, when `parent_id` is not `null`

How can I do this? thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a check constraint:

```
create table organizationns
(
  <other columns>, 
  parent_id integer,
  organization_type varchar(50) not null,
  constraint check_org_type 
    check (   (parent_id is null     and organization_type = 'ORG')
           or (parent_id is not null and organization_type = 'CLIENT')) 
);
```

---

But the `organization_type` column seems rather useless in that case, as you can always derive it from the `parent_id` (e.g. through a view)